# General way of pointing at All member of a hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

In our cubes it is somewhat hit and miss what the "All" member of each hiearchy is called:

For different hierarchies:

- HierX = [All]
- HierY = [All Y]
- HierZ = [All]
- HierJ = [All Js]

So sometimes the cube developer has left the default and other times he has made the name more verbose.

In my `mdx` I would like to be able to always find this member without worrying what it is named.

Assuming the hierarchy actually has an All member, can I assume that this code will always work? :

```
[DimensionX].[HierarchyX].members.item(0).item(0)
```

Is there a more water-tight approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [All] is what you need :

```
select [Geography].[Geography].[All] on 0 from [Adventure Works]
```

will show :

```
All Geographies
$80,450,596.98
```

To my knowledge [All] is a shortcut to the all-member of a hierarchy,